# Where is the "automatic (DHCP) addresses only" option in network?

Tags: dns, ip, ipv4

I am trying to change my DNS to Google Public following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?csw=1#linux).

However, my IPv4 settings lack this option. Why is it missing?

Comment: What options do you have?

Comment: I only have automatic(dchp), manual, link-local only, and shared with other computers

Comment: And the DNS entry fields - do they have options? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Not that I think: here's a link: http://imgur.com/a/Qamih

Comment: It looks like you have correctly set your DNS options. What is making you think that it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an "automatic (DHCP) addresses only" option because, in your software, "Automatic (DHCP)" is for the address only. Note how the drop down is labelled "Addresses". The DNS settings have a separate *Automatic* toggle, which you have turned off in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your dns information in different ways like :--
If you like to set in GUI just go to system setting then network then edit or create a new network and mention your private dns or google dns there.

Second way is to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file and add your dns address their if you want to give a static ip.

Third if you have installed dhcp server than mentions you dns information in dhcp server configuration file.

Hope it will work for you .......Thanks!!